# Weird Output Getting Ipaddress on eth0

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, network-programming, ip-address

I'm trying to get ip address of computer by C++ and some weird output has been shown.

here is my code:

```
 struct ifaddrs *ifadp,*tmp;
    char addrbuf[NI_MAXHOST] ;
    int s;
    getifaddrs(&ifadp);
    for(tmp = ifadp; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->ifa_next) {
        if(tmp->ifa_addr == NULL)
            continue;

        s = getnameinfo(tmp->ifa_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in),addrbuf,NI_MAXHOST,NULL,0,NI_NUMERICHOST);
        if(std::strcmp(tmp->ifa_name,"eth0")==0)
            std::cout << tmp->ifa_name<< " " << addrbuf<<std::endl;
    }
    freeifaddrs(ifadp);
        return 0;
```

and outputs:

```
eth0 �A`��
eth0 10.134.50.86
eth0 10.134.50.86
```

Any ideas about the first output?Meanwhile,OS is linux.

Comment: You don't check if `getnameinfo` succeeded, and if it fails, you are trying to output `addrbuf` which contains uninitialized data (and `std::cout` keeps printing any characters it runs into, until it reaches `\0` character). Consider initializing your arrays (in addition to checking for return value of `getnameinfo`): `char addrbuf[NI_MAXHOST] = {0};`.

Comment: Thanks in advice.You are right.We always must check returning value. Thanks again.